# XSLT ordering of renamed elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<order-information>
    <orderRecord>
        <order>
            <num_items>1</num_items>
            <orderNo>CA79268</orderNo>
            <ordDate>20160509</ordDate>
            <colorCode>YEL</colorCode>
            <sizeNo>LG</sizeNo>
            <ordRemarks />
            <catalogNo>00407</catalogNo>
        </order>
        <order>
            <num_items>1</num_items>
            <orderNo>CA79268</orderNo>
            <ordDate>20160509</ordDate>
            <colorCode>BLU</colorCode>
            <sizeNo>SM</sizeNo>
            <ordRemarks />
            <catalogNo>00424</catalogNo>
        </order>
        <order>
            <num_items>1</num_items>
            <orderNo>CA79268</orderNo>
            <ordDate>20160509</ordDate>
            <colorCode>GRN</colorCode>
            <sizeNo />
            <ordRemarks />
            <catalogNo>00499</catalogNo>
        </order>
    </orderRecord>
</order-information>
```

I need to rename most of the element names and then sort the `<order>` child elements by the new element name for use in a second application.  I also need to add two empty elements.  I have no control over the order of the elements in the source xml.  My XSLT attempt (a result of hours perusing this site for methods and examples):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Order Record -->
    <xsl:template match ="orderRecord/order">
        <xsl:element name="Group">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="order/catalogNo">
        <xsl:element name="V1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <!-- Add empty "V2" and "V3" -->
        <V2/>
        <V3/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="order/num_items">
        <xsl:element name="V4">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="order/orderNo">
        <xsl:element name="V5">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="order/ordDate">
        <xsl:element name="V6">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="order/colorCode">
        <xsl:element name="V7">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="order/sizeNo">
        <xsl:element name="V8">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="order/ordRemarks">
        <xsl:element name="V9">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Results in:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<order-information>
  <orderRecord>
    <Group>
      <V4>1</V4>
      <V5>CA79268</V5>
      <V6>20160509</V6>
      <V7>YEL</V7>
      <V8>LG</V8>
      <V9/>
      <V1>00407</V1>
      <V2/>
      <V3/>
    </Group>
    <Group>
      <V4>1</V4>
      <V5>CA79268</V5>
      <V6>20160509</V6>
      <V7>BLU</V7>
      <V8>SM</V8>
      <V9/>
      <V1>00424</V1>
      <V2/>
      <V3/>
    </Group>
    <Group>
      <V4>1</V4>
      <V5>CA79268</V5>
      <V6>20160509</V6>
      <V7>GRN</V7>
      <V8/>
      <V9/>
      <V1>00499</V1>
      <V2/>
      <V3/>
    </Group>
  </orderRecord>
</order-information>
```

But the second application needs the information in the following order:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<order-information>
  <orderRecord>
    <Group>
      <V1>00407</V1>
      <V2/>
      <V3/>
      <V4>1</V4>
      <V5>CA79268</V5>
      <V6>20160509</V6>
      <V7>YEL</V7>
      <V8>LG</V8>
      <V9/>
    </Group>
    <Group>
      <V1>00424</V1>
      <V2/>
      <V3/>
      <V4>1</V4>
      <V5>CA79268</V5>
      <V6>20160509</V6>
      <V7>BLU</V7>
      <V8>SM</V8>
      <V9/>
    </Group>
    <Group>
      <V1>00499</V1>
      <V2/>
      <V3/>
      <V4>1</V4>
      <V5>CA79268</V5>
      <V6>20160509</V6>
      <V7>GRN</V7>
      <V8/>
      <V9/>
    </Group>
  </orderRecord>
</order-information>
```

In effect, I need simply need rename "catalogNo" as "V1" and move so that it's the first element in each "order" node and then add the empty elements "V2" and "V3."  All of the other elements are in the proper order:

Is there a mechanism in XSLT to sort by an element's new name or some other method to get my information in the order needed by my second application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

You could force it by manually matching the children of `order`, like so:

```
<!-- Order Record -->
<xsl:template match ="orderRecord/order">
    <xsl:element name="Group">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="catalogNo"/> <!-- becomes V1, V2, V3 -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="num_items"/> <!-- becomes V4 -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="orderNo"/>   <!-- becomes V5 -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ordDate"/>   <!-- becomes V6 -->
        <!-- and so on -->
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

**Option 2**

If you really need sorting instead of such a handcrafted solution, a second pass might be interesting too. What I mean by that is: leave the `V*` tags unsorted then run a second XSLT sheet whose sole purpose is sorting the said tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Sort Group's children -->
  <xsl:template match="Group">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
      <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```